# SQL Server + HP Systems Insight Manager without Domain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7, server

I try to install HP Systems Insight Manager on Windows 7 PRO (32bit) without domain.

I have installed SQL Server (I have tried this since version from 2008 till 2014).

During installation I get a message:

> The specified database account credentials are not valid

User id `sa` - password is correct.

After check logs I saw logs like this:

> Handshake failed with error code: 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing connection....

next one is about domain:

> Login failed: The logon from an untrusted domain and cannot be user with Windows authentication.

Of course it doesn't matter if I login with Windows authentication or by user and password - I add user auth, and Its working with Management Studio. With SIM not !

I tried changing register and (I think a lot of google tips) but nothing works. Most of then are answers to not registered domains - but I don't have a domain. 
SIM and SQL are one the same machine (Win 7 prof but without domain)

Any suggestions ? ;)

Thanks

Comment: Tip on the side: ***don't use*** the `sa` account! Create a separate account for this application

Comment: I know. I was using this because I wanted to eliminate all possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

That was my stupid mistake, I was trying to put "\" as domain (domain in obligatory, it doesn't matter that I don't have it).
It worked when I put "/" as domain :)

Sorry for that :)